# After upgrading magento 2.3 to 2.4.2 error of create() on null file in Category/DataProvider.php

Tags: magento2

I've upgraded from magento 2.3 to magento 2.4.2 after which I'm getting the following error when opening "Categories" In Admin

**main.CRITICAL: Error: Call to a member function create() on null in**
`/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider.php:663`

> Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Good question, I have the exact same issue. For me the problem appears in some custom modules that plug into that DataProvider. As a workaround I replaced calling `parent::getFieldsMap()` with copying that parent function to my plugins, but that's not a very clean solution.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I have the same issue.

Comment: Look at the next line in the exception log to find the module causing the issue e.g
Stack trace:
#0 /data/web/stock/app/code/Bss/SeoCore/Plugin/Model/Category/DataProvider.php(82): Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider->getFieldsMap()
#1 /data/web/stock/generated/code/Bss/SeoCore/Plugin/Model/Category/DataProvider/Interceptor.php(41): Bss\SeoCore\Plugin\Model\Category\DataProvider->_getFieldsMap()

Shows the culprit as the bss module

Answer (score -1):

Find files by path /public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider.php. Find line 663 and replace

```
$config = $this->uiConfigFactory
            ->create(['componentName' => $referenceName])
            ->get($referenceName);
```

Converted into

```
$config = $this->uiConfigFactory
            ->create(['componentName' => 'category_form'])
            ->get($referenceName);
```

Comment: Editing core files aside, how is this supposed to fix the issue? The problem is that `uiConfigFactory` is `NULL` so calling its method causes an error. The problem is not that `$referenceName` is undefined.

Comment: Core modules will never fail unless you modify them or you use a third-party module to change its logic. So you can double check the extensions on your site.